# Magento 2 - Import product quantity is empty after product csv import

Tags: magento2, csv, magento2.3.1, product-import

In `Magento 2.3.1`, When I Go to admin panel

`System -> Import -> Products` and `Upload product CSV`.

Product imported with all information but miss qty, it shows empty.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated

Comment: Did you add 'qty' column heading with quantity in .CSV import sheet?